# How to store data obtained with retrofit into database

Tags: android, retrofit2, activeandroid

I have an android app and I'm getting data from web api with retrofit.

Now I need to save this data into my table. I'm using active android.

My table model "Partners", the data which I'm retrieving from web api and needs to be saved into this table Partners.

```
@Table(name = "Partners")
public class Partners extends Model {
    @Expose
    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String name;
    public Partners() {}
    public List<Partners> getPartners() { return getMany(Partners.class, "Partners");}
}
```

I have created ApiService

```
public interface APIService {    
    @GET("Partners")
    Call<Partners> getPartners();
}
```

I have api helper

```
public class APIHelper {

    public static APIService apiService;

    public static APIService getApiService() {
        if (apiService == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://here-is-part-of-link/partners.json")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        }
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

An this is my fragment where I'm trying to invoke method to get data from web api.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements Callback<Partners> {

    Button shippingFragment, deliveryFragment, measurementFragment, takeOversFragment;
    private Call<Partners> call;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, parent, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Title");
        shippingFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shipping);
        deliveryFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delivery);
        measurementFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.measurement);
        takeOversFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.take_overs);
        shippingFragment.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentListener);
        deliveryFragment.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentListener);
        measurementFragment.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentListener);
        takeOversFragment.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentListener);

        call = APIHelper.getApiService().getPartners();
        call.enqueue(this);

        return view;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnFragmentListener = (new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.shipping:
                    fragment = new ShippingFragment();
                    replaceFragment(fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.delivery:
                    fragment = new DeliveryMain();
                    replaceFragment(fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.measurement:
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MeasurementMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.take_overs:
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AllLogs.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    public void replaceFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment rFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, rFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Partners> call, Response<Partners> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Partners> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Error!!!!!!!!", String.valueOf(call));
    }
}
```

Now I need to save data into table "partners". I tried to do that in onResponse() method, but I failed.

**QUESTION: Could somebody help me with saving data from web api into database?**

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do like this inside onResponse

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Partners> call, Response<Partners> response) {

    List<Partners> partners = response.body().getPartners();
    //the response is stored in local object and now you can store it in sqlite db

    }
```

Comment: It uses getPartners() method from my model which retrieves all partners but now it is empty and throws null object reference

Comment: is your url `https://here-is-part-of-link/partners.json` valid ?? check with postman tool whether the api returns data

Comment: Checked...api returns data

Comment: can you share your logcat

Comment: I think the problem is with your model class. I recommend you to create model class from this **[website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)**. which is an excellent tool that automatically creates model class for you, just paste your api response there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118088/discussion-between-unknown19-and-saravinfern).